References for keisler-sheilah isomorphism.
I'm currently reading this article https://people.math.wisc.edu/~hkeisler/ultraproducts-web-final.pdf and I'm having some troubles finding a proof of theorem 10.5 and understanding why is it necessary to define good ultrafilters and what exactly are they. Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks!
To add up more context: I'm currently working on my final degree proyect. Up to date, I've talked about ultraproducts, the compactness theorem, lefschetz principle and types. In the last section, I want to prove the Keisler-Shelah isomorphism theorem without GCH. The theorem is the following:
Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a language of cardinal $|\mathcal{L}|= \kappa$. Consider two  $\mathcal{L}$-structures $\mathcal{M}$, $\mathcal{N}$ such that its universes are of cardinal $\leq \kappa^+$. Then, $\mathcal{M} \equiv \mathcal{N}$ iff there exists a countably incomplete good ultrafilter $U$ over a set $I$ of cardinal $\kappa$ (or $\kappa$ itself) such that $\mathcal{M}^I / U \cong \mathcal{N}^I / U$ .
Definitions of countably incomplete and good ultrafilters can be found in sections 5.2 and 10.1 of the linked article. Any insights on this topic will be really helpful, so please feel free to comment anything on the topic :)

Keisler gives two references. What did you find when you looked at these references?

Another good reference (which may also provide more background and motivation) is Section 6.1 of the book Model Theory by Chang and Keisler.

@AlexKruckman I've just found out that theorem 2.1 of reference [22] is what I need in order to understand the whole thing. Nonetheless, I'm finding great difficulties in "translating" Keisler's notation to the notation I'm familiar with, and I'm not really seeing the proof itself. My objective is to proof that two structures are elementary equivalent iff there is an countably incomplete good ultrafilter $U$ over $I$ such that the ultrapowers of the structures are isomorphic, without using GCH.

The context helps. If you want to prove Keisler-Shelah without GCH, then Theorem 10.5 is not relevant. In the absence of GCH, "good" is not good enough - Shelah's proof involves a much more intricate ultrafilter construction. But that said, it's a great idea to understand good ultrafilters and Keisler's simpler proof using GCH first.

@AlexKruckman do you know any other references that might help me proving Keisler-Shelah without GCH, apart from the book you cited? I'm reading the original proof from Shelah, but I'm kind of stuck. I would love to be able to understand the proof and include it in my final degree project.

I don't know of any clearer presentation of the proof than the one given by Chang and Keisler in Model Theory.
